# JTextField enlarges in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, layout, netbeans, gridbaglayout

of course sorry for my bad English. I'm working on a window in which I have a panel and the panel within a form. The panel uses the distribution manager "GridBagLayout" I could properly distribute the components. My problem is that when filling a text field, type in the (JTextField) enlarges the field and does not retain its size. As you can see from the picture the more letters introduce the "Brand" field is becoming bigger. I'm working with NetBeans if someone happened or know what can be the problem Thanks in advance. Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about how to do this with a window editor like they have in NetBeans, but for GridBagLayout the power comes with how you configure your GridBagConstraints when you add another Component. If you want to keep every Component on a given row to keep their ratios fixed, then you need to define each of their GridBagConstraints.weightX fields to sum up to 1. So if you want something like:

|Label|TextField|Blank|

I would add Label with GridBagConstraints.weightX=0.3, TextField with GridBagConstraints.weightX=0.3, and a final "empty" Label("") as a buffer with GridBagConstraints.weightX=0.4. Total = 1.

There are of course tutorials available  [GridBag Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)